# Rails form_for NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I am trying to generate a form using erb in a rails application. I am continually getting the NoMethodError for line #3 of my .html.erb file. Below is the migration, the controller, the model, and the .html.erb

The error is "undefined method `class_projects_path'"

Migration:

```
class CreateClassProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration  
  def change  
    create_table :class_projects do |t|  
      t.string :name  
      t.text :description  
      t.text :summary  
      t.text :github  
      t.text :other_url  

      t.timestamps  
    end  
  end  
end
```

Model:

```
class ClassProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :github, :name, :other_url, :summary
end
```

Controller:

```
class ClassProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @class_project = ClassProject.new
  end
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<h1>New Class Project</h1>

   <%= form_for @class_project do |f| %>

   <%= f.label :name %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>

   <%= f.label :description %>
   <%= f.text_field :description %>

   <%= f.label :summary %>
   <%= f.text_field :summary %>

   <%= f.label :github %>
   <%= f.text_field :github %>

   <%= f.label :other_url %>
   <%= f.text_field :other_url %>

<% end %>
```

Route for good measure:

```
get 'new_project' => 'class_projects#new', :as => 'new'
```

Thanks for any help, inb4 learn to code nub, use the search function nub, etcetera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :class_projects
```

This means you'll be able to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/class_projects_controller.rb
class ClassProjectsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @class_project = ClassProject.new
   end
end

#app/views/class_projects/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @class_project do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

--

**Routes**

The problem you have is that you have not declared a full compliment of routes for your `class_projects` objects. Rails runs a [`resourceful`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) ([object orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)) routing system, meaning that if you invoke the `resources` directive, you'll be provided with a full CRUD routing structure:

[image]

This means that if you use a helper such as `form_for` (which builds routes based on your provided object), you'll *have* to have this CRUD compliment of routes set up.

Defining your routes file as above will give you the ability to call the `form_for` helper with impunity (and no extra arguments)

Comment: Thanks, I added :url => 'new' as an argument to over ride the default form action in the form_for method call. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

you didn't define a resources route, so your form needs an extra config

```
<%= form_for @class_project, url: new_path do |f| %
```

Comment: Route should be changed to create path

Comment: he named his route `as: 'new'`

Comment: well ya ok, i guess he needs another route for the post