# Rails (erb) labelling fields / areas causing NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So I searched all the results around the above title and none of them are giving me a solution - [one thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734405/rails-form-for-nomethoderror) came close but wasn't right.

My RoR code inside new.html.erb:

```
<div class="row">
    <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field %>

        <%= f.label :comments %>
        <%= f.text_area %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Causing the following error:
[Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upPsn.png)

My routes.rb file has:

```
resources :contacts
```

My contacts.rb file:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base  
end
```

My contacts_controller file:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @contact = Contact.new
    end

    def create
    end
end
```

So I need to find what I did wrong - I do not want to have to start from scratch again :(

Comment: Do you have a column called `name` in your `Contact` model?  Maybe you can post your schema.rb (under the db folder) to confirm what fields you have defined in the model.

Comment: This is what I found in my db file: class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.text :comments
      
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Comment: and this is in my schema.rb file : ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151117210757) do

  create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
  end

end

Comment: It looks like your schema doesn't include the fields specified in your migration.  Did you modify the migration file AFTER you ran it?  That's a no no.   Try doing `rake db:rollback` to cancel the last migration, then do `rake db:migrate` to run it again and this time the schema should include your `name` and `email` and `comments` fields as well as your timestamps.

Comment: Schweeeet - thanks a bunch. Fixed it!! Such a simple thing... damn my life.

Comment: I just copied pasted your answer below and referenced you. So that the thread can be closed and answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Steve Turczyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2516474/steveturczyn)

It looks like your schema doesn't include the fields specified in your migration. Did you modify the migration file AFTER you ran it? That's a no no.

Try doing

```
rake db:rollback
```

to cancel the last migration, 
then do

```
rake db:migrate
```

to run it again and this time the schema should include your name and email and comments fields as well as your timestamps